# Jackson 2 - Deserialize String directly to Date with Retrofit REST-API on Android

Tags: android, date, jackson, retrofit

I am working on deserializing a json containing a java.util.Date as String in the format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss". My goal is to get it parsed into a date, so I can access it later as java.util.Date.

My POJO contains the following:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "id",
    "dateTime",
    "currentPeriod",
    (...)
})
public class MatchItem {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("dateTime")
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
    private Date dateTime;

    @JsonProperty("currentPeriod")
    private int currentPeriod;

    (...)

    @JsonProperty("dateTime")
    public Date getDateTime() {
        return dateTime;
    }

    @JsonProperty("dateTime")
    public void setDateTime(Date dateTime) {
        this.dateTime = dateTime;
    }
```

Then I use a REST API (Retrofit) to directly deserialize my servers json response. With leaving the date in string format it works, but when I try to deserialize it into a java.util.Date directly it doesn't?

How can I make it work?

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: When you deserialize Date directly what format do you use? Have you looked at the desrialization section in this document: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end I didn't find a way to do what I wanted to do with only Jackson annotations, I fixed it by implementing a custom converter for retrofit like so:

```
JacksonConverter matchItemConverter = new JacksonConverter(Utils.getHwObjectMapper());
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
    .setEndpoint(URL)
    .setConverter(matchItemConverter)
    .build();
```

When creating the objectmapper, make sure to add the date format:

```
public static ObjectMapper getHwObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper hWObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    hWObjectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH));
    return hWObjectMapper;
}
```

And make this your converter based on Jackson:

```
public class JacksonConverter implements Converter {
private final ObjectMapper mapper;

public JacksonConverter(ObjectMapper mapper) {
    this.mapper = mapper;
}

@Override public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) throws ConversionException
{
    String charset = "UTF-8";
    if (body.mimeType() != null) {
        charset = MimeUtil.parseCharset(body.mimeType());
    }

    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    try {
        isr = new InputStreamReader(body.in(), charset);
        return mapper.readValue(isr, TypeFactory.rawClass(type));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ConversionException(e);
    } finally {
        if (isr != null) {
            try {
                isr.close();
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
                ignored.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override public TypedOutput toBody(Object object) {
    try {
        return new JsonTypedOutput(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(object));
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}

private static class JsonTypedOutput implements TypedOutput {
    private final byte[] jsonBytes;

    JsonTypedOutput(byte[] jsonBytes) {
        this.jsonBytes = jsonBytes;
    }

    @Override public String fileName() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override public String mimeType() {
        return "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    }

    @Override public long length() {
        return jsonBytes.length;
    }

    @Override public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.write(jsonBytes);
    }
}
}
```